# escape slash in php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to execute a preg_match with PHP but I can not escape the slash properly. The preg_match should return subsrting between Prozessor and first slash

```
$str="Prozessor: AMD A-Serie A8-4500M / 19 GHz ( 28 GHz ) /";

preg_match('/Prozessor: (.*) \//', $str, $matches)

Prozessor: AMD A-Serie A8-4500M / 19 GHz ( 28 GHz ) /
```

I would like to get the name of the Processor which should give me back

```
AMD A-Serie A8-4500M
```

What I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
preg_match('/Prozessor: (.*?) \//', $str, $matches)
```

Or a character class:

```
preg_match('/Prozessor: ([^\/]*) \//', $str, $matches)
```

Also note, if you change your regex delimiter, you won't have to worry about escaping it:

```
preg_match('#Prozessor: ([^/]*) /#', $str, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/Prozessor: (.*?) \//`.  This will replace a [greedy selector with a lazy selector](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).  Example:

```
$str="Prozessor: AMD A-Serie A8-4500M / 19 GHz ( 28 GHz ) /";
preg_match('/Prozessor: (.*?) \//', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
// string(33) "Prozessor: AMD A-Serie A8-4500M"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$str="Prozessor: AMD A-Serie A8-4500M / 19 GHz ( 28 GHz ) /";
preg_match('/^Prozessor: (?P<prozessor>[a-z0-9\s-]+) \//i', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches['prozessor']);
```

outputs

```
string(20) "AMD A-Serie A8-4500M"
```

Or alternatively, you could add an ungreedy modifier to the end of your regex:

```
preg_match('/Prozessor: (.*) \//U', $str, $matches)
```

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php